# How to rename JPG image files and insert dashes and dots in date/time in the file names?

Tags: windows, cmd, rename, command-prompt

I have some files such as:

- 20220716_165615-IMG_1234.jpg
- 20220717_102742-IMG_1235.jpg
- 20220717_193212-IMG_1236.jpg

They need to be renamed to:

- 2022-07-16_16.56.15-IMG_1234.jpg
- 2022-07-17_10.27.42-IMG_1235.jpg
- 2022-07-17_19.32.12-IMG_1236.jpg

I tried using a rename in Windows 10 CMD:

```
ren ????????_??????-*.* ????-??-??_??.??.??-*.*
```

But I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's easier with windows powershell:
for the current folder:

```
Get-Item .\*.* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(15,'.') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
Get-Item .\*.* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(13,'.') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
Get-Item .\*.* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(6,'-') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
Get-Item .\*.* | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(4,'-') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

for the contents of the subfolders:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(11,'.') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(6,'-') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(4,'-') + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
```

(the -WhatIf argument shows what's about to be done. To execute it for real, remove the -WhatIf argument)